# How to embed image link in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I want to add image from remote server. I have image link such as http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/114/5095827-image.jpg
But drupal is giving only upload image option. I don't want to store image. I want to display it without storing.

Comment: Where do you want to add the image? Give us the details !

Comment: In image field, i want to add link as source but there is only upload option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi if you are running drupal 8, there is a module "**Remote Image**" to handle this https://www.drupal.org/project/remote_image

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with the default image field. (Assuming you are using Drupal 8)
What you can do is use a plain text field to input and store the image URL and use the field value later in your template files as image source.
Alternatively you can use ck-editor directly to upload image or use external image urls, to use external URLs only you will need to uncheck "Enable image uploads" option in admin > configuration > text formats and editors > configure(your desired text format basic/full/restricted etc).